# Handbrake batch convert script assistance to set output extension specified by the official presets

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-scripting, handbrake

With the help of numerous discussions on SE network and other places I finally managed to a working script that works well except the Matroska presets. I understand the problem is the script itself, since it specifies destination extension as MP4. 
I am zero experienced with bash and couldn't figure out how to improve the script so instead of pre-setting the output extension, it will take extensions as specified by the [official presets](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/technical/official-presets.html). 
Most of the presets container is MP4 so it works for most presets except MKV.
Here is an example of the script that works for MP4:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Configure these as needed
SRC=~/hbCLI/src
DEST=~/hbCLI/dest
DEST_EXT=mp4
HANDBRAKE_CLI=HandBrakeCLI
PRESET="Fast 480p30"
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
# The script itself
for FILE in `ls $SRC`
do
filename=$(basename $FILE)
extension=${filename##*.}
filename=${filename%.*}
$HANDBRAKE_CLI -i $SRC/$FILE -o $DEST/$filename.$DEST_EXT --preset="$PRESET" --optimize --two-pass
done
```

However for Matroska presets I only need to change the line `PRESET="Fast 480p30"` to `PRESET="H.264 MKV 480p30"` but the output extension is still `mp4` instead of `mkv`.

**Additional request:**
Not part of the question but if any of you could help me to improve the script further so the output is saved to `DEST=~/hbCLI/dest/$PRESET` instead of `DEST=~/hbCLI/dest`meaning the output will be saved into a folder with the preset name, if it doesn't exist- create the folder. 
Thank you!

Comment: If you manually have to enter the preset name, wouldn't it be easiest do just manually add the extension as well?

Comment: @slhck Yes that is exactly what how I am managing right now but for that I would have to know the preset container format. That's why I was looking for a way if the container format could be automatically selected as per the preset.

Comment: I thought the name of the container was already part of the name of the preset, as shown in your example? (That is, `PRESET="H.264 MKV 480p30` means it's using MKV)

Comment: Not all preset names are that informative, for example 'Gmail Large 3 Minutes 720p30'. Still I see your point have undeniable logic. I guess I am trying to make things as much automatic as possible. A less input probably :)

Comment: I can have a look later, but in principle you could look up where Handbrake saves its presets (my guess is that they're just plaintext files somewhere on your machine), from which you can read the requried extension. There are some tweaks you could do in your script to automate it. (I assume your goal is to encode the same input file, or multiple input files, with all available presets, or at least a selected subset of those?)

Comment: Exactly! And thank you for your consideration. Waiting in anticipation.

Comment: Which OS are you on? The presets seem to be stored in a JSON file under `~/Library/Application Support/HandBrake/UserPresets.json`, so it's going to be a little more complex to read them from a Bash script. In fact, it may be simpler to use Python to parse that data.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: how do you decide on what preset you want? maybe you could think about selecting your preset based on file type. if $extension = mkv then $preset = $presetmkv else $presetmp4